# Performing multiple operations if condition is satisfied in ternary operator in linq

Tags: linq

I am a beginner in LINQ.I want to perform some conditional operation lik follows,

```
(from emp in Employees 
let DOB=emp.BirthDate.GetValueOrDefault()
let year=DOB.Year
let month=DOB.Month
let EmpAgeInYearsToday=DateTime.Now.Year-year
let EmpAgeInMonthToday=DateTime.Now.Month-month
let temp_year=(EmpAgeInYearsToday-1)
let ExactNoOfMonths_temp=EmpAgeInMonthToday<0?temp_year:EmpAgeInMonthToday
let ExactNoOfMonths=EmpAgeInMonthToday<0?EmpAgeInMonthToday+12&temp_year:EmpAgeInMonthToday
select new{emp.EmployeeID,DOB,
EmployeeAgeToday=EmpAgeInYearsToday+" Years "+ExactNoOfMonths+" Months ").Dump();
```

Here,

let ExactNoOfMonths=EmpAgeInMonthToday<0?EmpAgeInMonthToday+12&temp_year:EmpAgeInMonthToday

This part is not working. The expression in the left side of & alone is getting executed.I want to perform both the operations. How to achieve this?How to perform multiple operations when the condition is satisfied?
 Is there any Other alternate way for doing this?

Comment: _"This part is not working"_ does not tell much about the exception or wrong behaviour.

Comment: When i give lik this, the expression in the left side of & alone is getting executed.I want to perform both the operations.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `EmpAgeInMonthToday+12&temp_year` to _do_? What this says is "add 12 to `EmpAgeInMonthToday`, _perform a bitwise AND with `temp_year`_, and return the result". Are you _sure_ this is what you want, and are you _sure_ it's not what's happening?

Comment: I want EmpAgeInMonthToday+12 and temp_year both to get calcuted and to get reflected in my resultant table when EmpAgeInMonthToday<0 is satisfied. I am confused about the way which i have to follow to perform this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you mean is something like this:

```
ExactNoOfMonths = EmpAgeInMonthToday < 0 ?
                      EmpAgeInMonthToday + 12 :
                      temp_year ? 
                          EmpAgeInMonthToday :
                          somethingElse
```

but there should be a third value (`somethingElse`) for when `EmpAgeInMonthToday >= 0` and `temp_year = false`.

**Edit**

What you want is actually pretty complicated. You better just fetch the dates of birth in memory and do the calculation in plain C#.

[This CodeProject link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28837/Calculating-Duration-Between-Two-Dates-in-Years-Mo) gives a possible approach. As you'll see you can't avoid leap years and month lengths: the difference between Feb 28 and Mar 28 is 1 month in a normal year, 1 month and 1 day in a leap year.

Comment: What I want to do is if EmpAgeInMonthToday < 0 is true 12 shud get added with EmpAgeInMonthToday and year shud get reduced by 1(the temp_year part). Your answer is taking the temp_year part as a condition. I want to perform it as an operation if my condition is satisfied.

Comment: You can't do that with a ternary operator. It returns a value and does not execute statements. But maybe we should step back a little. Can't you solve this by calculating differences between date values?

Comment: I can do that but here what i need to calculate is the Age of Employees in no of days,months and years. So it will be a tedious process to get the no of days ,months and years from the difference value.And in that case i have to calculate each and every details such as leap year,months which has 31 and 30 days.. etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gert.That link cleared all my doubts regarding date calculations.:)